# Acceso restringido de usuario

Tags: android, firebase, login, real-time, access-control

Estoy haciendo una app similar a uber pero para transporte público como proyecto de la escuela.

Mi problema es que cuando entro al login del usuario, puedo ingresar con el correo del chofer y viceversa, cosa que no quiero que suceda.

La intención es que los usuarios solo puedan ingresar con los correos registrados en "Usuarios" y el conductor del bus solo pueda ingresar con correo registrador en "Conductores".

[image: Así mi estructura en Firebase]

Ya investigué en las mismas guías de la plataforma pero no encuentro como tal lo que busco. ¿Alguna idea? Se los agradecería mucho.

Esto es por ejemplo el login para el chofer:

```
public class chofer00 extends AppCompatActivity {

//Declaración de mis objetos
Button loginchofer00;
EditText nipchofer00,passwordchofer00;
RadioButton btnsesionchofer;
boolean sesionactiva;
private static final String STRING_PREFERENCES="email.password";
private static final String PREFERENCE_ESTADO_BUTTON_SESION="estado.button.sesion";
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthlistener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chofer00);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    firebaseAuthlistener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser Users = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (Users!=null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(chofer00.this, chofer01.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;

            }
        }
    };

    //SI SE HABÍA PEDIDO NO CERRAR SESIÓN ENTONCES NO HABRÁ LOGIN
    if (obtenerestadobtn()){
        Intent ingresochofer = new Intent(chofer00.this,chofer01.class);
        startActivity(ingresochofer);
    }

    //RELACIÓN DE OBJETOS CREADOS CON EL LAYOUT
    loginchofer00=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginchofer00);
    nipchofer00=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nipchofer00);
    passwordchofer00=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordchofer00);
    btnsesionchofer=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.sesionchofer);

    //CAMBIO DE ACTIVIDAD CON EL BOTÓN DE LOGIN
    loginchofer00.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {//BUSQUEDA EN LA BD
            final String email = nipchofer00.getText().toString();
            final String pass = passwordchofer00.getText().toString();
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(chofer00.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(chofer00.this, "Error de inicio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo quieres que un determinado email pueda loguearse, ya sea conductor o usuario, lo que deberias hacer es lo siguiente.

Cuando haces el click para loguear a un usuario, obtenes el email y la password que vas a pasar al metodo `signInWithUserAndPassword(...)` para poder ingresar con cualquier usuario.

Ahora, antes de hacer esto, podes chequear si el email se encuentra tanto en usuarios como en conductores.

Viendo tu base de datos, guardas el user ID de cada usuario y conductor dentro de los nodos `conductores` y `usuarios`, asumo que dentro de estos nodos tenes un campo email con el email de cada usuario.

Para solucionar este problema solo haces una peticion de los datos de ese usuario una vez logueado para realizar la accion que necesites.

```
private DatabaseReference mEmailRef;

final String email = nipchofer00.getText().toString();
            final String pass = passwordchofer00.getText().toString();
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(chofer00.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                 if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                  mEmailRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              String authEmail = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
              if(authEmail.equals(email)) //hace tu operacion 
              else //error
          }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
             System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
              }  
           });

                    }
                }
            });
```

No esta muy alineado el codigo, pero la logica es esta, una vez que te logueas con el usuario, obtenes el uid del usuario logueado, vas a su nodo, buscas su email y lo comparas con el email ingresado en el edittext, si esta en la lista podes hacer una accion, sino no.

Te recomiendo que veas la api **AuthResult** que es lo que devuelve el **Task** que loguea a un usuario

[AuthResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult.html#getUser())

Y esto es lo que podes obtener con `getUser()`

[FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html)

Comment: Me sirvió tu respuesta, al parecer ya ejecuta la comparación (aunque lo cambie por comparar ID's para que fuese más fácil por el momento).
Ahora solo me genera un error al ingresar a la actividad en caso de ser autenticado como chofer, pero será cuestión de revisar la ejecución.
Pero tu respuesta sí me ayudó, muchas gracias.

Comment: Si tienes otra consulta, puedes generar otra pregunta, un saludo